# List of objects - get object fields distinct count

Tags: java

For a list of objects I have to check for (some) fields:

- all objects having same value for that field
- all objects having a different value for that field

```java
class Person {
   final String name;
   final int age;
   final int group;

   public Person( final String name, final int age, final int group ) {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
      this.group = group;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return this.name;
   }

   public int getAge() {
      return this.age;
   }

   public int getGroup() {
      return this.group;
   }
}

public static <T> long distinctByField( final List<Person> personList, final Function<Person, T> field ) {
   return personList.stream()
         .map( field )
         .distinct().count();
}

public static void main( final String[] args ) {
   final List<Person> personList = Arrays.asList(
         new Person( "Fred", 25, 1 ),
         new Person( "Bill", 22, 1 ),
         new Person( "Fred", 27, 1 ),
         new Person( "Lisa", 25, 1 )
   );

   System.out.println( distinctByField( personList, Person::getName ) );
   System.out.println( distinctByField( personList, Person::getAge ) );
   System.out.println( distinctByField( personList, Person::getGroup ) );
}
```

With result of stream/distinct/count I can compare with current list size:

- if count == 1 : all objects having same value for that field
- if count == list.size : all objects having different value for that field

Drawback is, i have to stream for every interested field.

Is it possible to do this with one query (for a list of interested fields) ?

Comment: Looking at your needs, you will need to run for each field separately. However, you could make this a bit more declaritive with annotations on the fields and running some reflection to detect those fields and run the check on those fields.

This will make it open/closed, but also more complex.

Comment: What did you mean by *Is it possible to do this with one query (for a list of interested fields) ?*

Comment: @YCF_L: I mean a simpler statement so as not to stream separately for each field

Comment: @p.streef: what about an own collector with accumulate/combine/finish ?

Comment: you would be able to compile a report from a list ofcourse, but that would then mean you still accumulate over the separate fields. Basically, in the information you are looking for the fields themselves have no relation, so the fact that they are in 1 object does not help, they could just have been 3 separate lists of values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible using reflection:

```
public class ReflectionTest {

    class Person {
        final String name;
        final int age;
        final int group;

        public Person(final String name, final int age, final int group) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.group = group;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return this.age;
        }

        public int getGroup() {
            return this.group;
        }
    }

    @DisplayName("should determine distinct fields")
    @Test
    public void distinct() {
        final List<Person> personList = Arrays.asList(new Person("Fred", 25, 1),
                                                      new Person("Bill", 22, 1),
                                                      new Person("Fred", 27, 1),
                                                      new Person("Lisa", 25, 1));
        Map<String,Long> fieldCountMap = Stream.of("name", "age", "group")
                                                  .map(fieldName -> ReflectionUtils.findField(Person.class, fieldName))
                                                  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Field::getName, field -> personList.stream().map(person -> getField(field, person)).distinct().count()));

        assertEquals(3,fieldCountMap.get("name"));
        assertEquals(1,fieldCountMap.get("group"));
        assertEquals(3,fieldCountMap.get("age"));
    }

    //extracted into a method because field.get throws a checked exception
    Object getField(Field field, Person object) {
        try {
            return field.get(object);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I feel in contrast to the other proposed answers this solution actually does exactly what you asked for, for "a list of interesting fields". In software what is interesting today might not be interesting tomorrow, so that is where you need to build for change.

Comment: Note that to be really open closed here you should "get" the list by using reflection as well, for instance by adding annotations on the "interesting" fields

Answer (score 0):

Let me first mention: This is a more or less huge downside in code quality (searching manually through all fields, using an extra class to store the results). And I doubt, this would be more efficient in terms of computation time or memory. By logic you will have to touch every field of every person and store values that already occured in order to find the distinct count for every field. Which is exactly what your solution with 3 streams does. I'd advice you to stay with it.

But here is a solution. I built a collector, that collects in one run all the different values for each field into a custom class.

```
  static class PersonStatistic {
    Set<String> names = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Integer> ages = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Integer> groups = new HashSet<>();
  }
  
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final List<Person> personList = Arrays.asList(
        new Person("Fred", 25, 1),
        new Person("Bill", 22, 1),
        new Person("Fred", 27, 1),
        new Person("Lisa", 25, 1));

    PersonStatistic personStatistic = personList.stream().collect(
        // Create new Statistic
        PersonStatistic::new, 
        // Merge A Person into statistic
        (statistic, person) -> {
          statistic.names.add(person.name);
          statistic.ages.add(person.age);
          statistic.groups.add(person.group);
        },
        // Merge second statistic into first
        (stat1, stat2)-> {
          stat1.names.addAll(stat2.names);
          stat1.ages.addAll(stat2.ages);
          stat1.groups.addAll(stat2.groups);
        });

    System.out.println(personStatistic.names.size());
    System.out.println(personStatistic.ages.size());
    System.out.println(personStatistic.groups.size());
  }
```

Comment: have already considered that, but as you already mentioned it seems a bit to much for the present issue